# Make a control on the form go right and up or left and up when two keys are pressed?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I am trying to make a game where you are a guy, and (yes, there is gravity) and you are on the bottom of the form. You can move right and left (it is a picture box) and when you jump you go up and then go back down. I want to make it so that if you press the right arrow key and the space bar you jump to the right a bit, and same with the left, but im not sure how to do it. I've tried:

```
int pX = Player.Location.X;
int pY = Player.Location.Y;     

if (e.KeyData == Keys.Space && e.KeyData == Keys.Right)
{
                        Player.Location = new Point(pX + 15, pY -= 30);
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                        Player.Location = new Point(pX + 15, pY -= 30);
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                        Player.Location = new Point(pX + 15, pY -= 30);
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                        Player.Location = new Point(pX + 15, pY += 30);
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                        Player.Location = new Point(pX + 15, pY += 30);
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                        Player.Location = new Point(pX + 15, pY += 30);
}
```

But that didnt work. Thanks for your help !!

Comment: What event did you put it?

Comment: @Christmas Unicorn I put it under form1 keydown

Comment: Are you sure `Form1` has focus and will pick the keydown event?

Comment: what? how do i do that?

Comment: Make sure you put `this.Focus();` in Form_Load or constructor

Comment: Alright, I will do that now

Answer (score 0):

Except for modifier keys (like `Alt`, `Ctrl`, `Shift`) WinForms cannot detect simultaneous key presses. Pressing two keys other than modifier keys will fire distinct key events.

This answer to "Catching multiple keys pressed in C# WinForm" might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7780135/880990.

Gaming interfaces like DirectInput have support for multiple key inputs. E.g. you can detect `Up Arrow` and `Right Arrow` pressed simultaneously.

You could also try to keep trak of `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` events for the different keys in order to get their state.

Also you will be better off using a `Timer` and do the game logic in a `Tick` event handler. Other than `Sleep`, this gives you a real chance to detect simultaneous keys pressed, as the key events will occur between the ticks.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to track multiple keys being pressed with the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events you have to do some manual tracking:

```
bool spacePressed, rightPressed;

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Space)
        spacePressed = true;

    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Right)
        rightPressed = true;

    Console.WriteLine("Space: " + spacePressed + " Right: " + rightPressed);
}

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Space)
        spacePressed = false;

    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Right)
        rightPressed = false;

    Console.WriteLine("Space: " + spacePressed + " Right: " + rightPressed);
}
```

The `e.KeyData` will only hold a single key press and boolean operations can not be used to determine keys pressed.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Do not use the values in this enumeration for combined bitwise
>   operations. The values in the enumeration are not mutually exclusive.